# Creating process.env variables using AWS Amplify?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js

With serverless we can add `process.env` variables by creating a configuration file entry like this:

```
environment:
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: ${self:custom.secrets.stripeSecretKey} # Stripe secret API key
```

And we can access it in our lambda function like this:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

How do we do this with AWS Amplify?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I am trying the same because i need to set a different hostedUi Path for local and uploaded environment

Comment: Looks like we can add them manually like this, all though that's outside of the Amplify workflow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add variables at your Amplify environment configuration.
You can also add variable overrides and select a branch that's gonna use it.

DOCS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html

Comment: These are not available in `process.env`.

Comment: It actually works @devth - but it requires re-deploying the stack

Comment: I didn't get it working. After contacting AWS Premium support I've said it's not going to work so I had put keys right into lambda function as config and manage values with 
`process.env.ENV === "production" ? PRODUCTION_KEY : STAGING_KEY`

Comment: when I create an amplify function and have environment variable in there, I can't seem to create a function which gets these variables passed through. are you saying any lambda functions you create after you add the env vars, will have those env vars passed into that function?

Comment: These are build time variables, not for backend / lambda functions

Answer (score 1):

Using Amplify environment variable in lambda is unavailable at the moment.

Btw, what you can do is referring to the name of backend environment in lambda.

It would be automatically set if you create lambda with amplify.

For example, you can get the name of your backend environment name with `os.environ['ENV']` in python lambda.

Comment: this seems to be the proper answer

Answer (score 1):

After a year+ of development using amplify framework I figured that you can only specify ENV VARIABLE form from your front-end build process. for lambdas it's a bit tricky. You can add a condition `"IsProductionEnv"` which is going to place value to ENV Variables for that function depending on amplify env.
for production I use `"prod"` you can use whatever you want.
go to your `amplify/backend/function/{functionName}` folder.
there should be `{functionName}-cloudformation-template.json` file.
you need to add one more item to `"Conditions"` object:

```
"Conditions":{
  ...,
  "IsProductionEnv": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "env"
        },
        "prod"
      ]
    }
}
```

then you need to use that condition at `"Resources.Properties.Environment.Variables"` :

```
       "Environment": {
          "Variables": {
            ...,
            "STRIPE_PK": {
              "Fn::If": [
                "IsProductionEnv",
                "pk_live_...",
                "pk_test_..."
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I have "dev" and "prod" amplify env names. it will handle your deployments and manage your env variables based on env for that function.

Answer (score 0):

For secrets such as Stripe API keys, they should never be visible to a user.

With Amplify CLI you can add a secret to each lambda function which will allow you to access a secret for each environment. [View here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/secrets/)

You can run `amplify function update` for existing functions or when you create a `amplify function add` there will be a prompt to add a secret.

Here is sample node lambda code to access the secret:

```
const { SSM } = require('aws-sdk');

...


  const { Parameters: [ stripeSecretData ] } = await ( new SSM() )
      .getParameters({
        Names: [ 'STRIPE_SECRET_KEY' ].map(secretName => process.env[ secretName ]),
        WithDecryption: true
      })
      .promise();

    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = stripeSecretData.Value;
```

When you checkout into another environment and push you will be prompted to add a secret for that new environment if one doesn't exist.

Note there is costs for using AWS secrets manager https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/pricing/ and you must create 1 secret per lambda function.